# Scala Generics - T has method restrictions

Tags: scala

I am new with scala generics, I have read multiple articles about views, type bound/context bound. When I have tried to implement my class, I was really confused.

My question is, let's say I have a template class **MyClass[T]{}**. I want that **T** must have some methods for example :

```
def func1(t:T):T
def func2(t:T):Boolean
def func3(t:T):Unit
```

Note: classes that will use **MyClass** are not **T** therefore I cannot use :< or  :>

I have read about Ordered and Ordering that have implicit function, but I still cannot figure out how to implement it.

Thanks for helpers

Comment: By the way, you might be interested to look at [structural types](http://daily-scala.blogspot.ru/2010/02/introducing-structural-types.html). Not saying it will solve problem above, but might give you another way to archive it.

Comment: Scala does not have "template classes" in the C++ sense. It has generic classes in the Java / JVM sense. Specifically (and ignoring specialization) it uses type erasure to create a single `.class` for the generic class. That single JVM class serves _all_ instantiations of the generic class.

Comment: ... and this is the [difference between *reified generics* (the ones in .NET) and non-reified (JVM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Comparison_of_C_Sharp_and_Java&oldid=503563938#Type_erasure_versus_reified_generics).

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you're asking. Is it T that needs the listed methods, or is it MyClass? In particular I don't understand the meaning of your Note (classes that will use MyClass are not T...)? Would you mind to clarify this aspects, please?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with typeclasses. Create a `trait`, that contains the methods you need and for every type that should be supported create an implicit instance:

```
trait MyTypeClass[T] {
  def func1(t:T):T
  def func2(t:T):Boolean
  def func3(t:T):Unit
}

implicit object MyTypeClassInt extends MyTypeClass[Int] {
  def func1(t:Int) = t + 2
  def func2(t:Int) = t > 4
  def func3(t:Int) = println(s"t is: $t")
}
```

Now if you add a context bound to the type parameter in your class, it can only be instantiated, when an instance for the given type is in scope.

```
class MyClass[A : MyTypeClass](a: A)

scala> new MyClass(2)
res0: MyClass[Int] = MyClass@47825164

scala> new MyClass("")
<console>:11: error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type MyTypeClass[String]
              new MyClass("")**
```

You can access the instance in your class by calling `implicitly[MyTypeClass[A]]`. Alternatively you can do one of the following things:

1.) Instead of using a context bound add an implicit parameter to your class:

```
class MyClass[A](a: A)(implicit ev: MyTypeClass[A])
```

2.) Add a companion for your typeclass, that has an apply method, that implicitly retrieves the instance and returns it:

```
object MyTypeClass {
  def apply[A](implicit ev: MyTypeClass[A]) = ev
}
```

and use it in your class like this:

```
MyTypeClass[A].func1(a)
```